# How to brighten the face of a backlit subject

Tags: flash, digital, backlight

I want to recreate a photo like the below one.

[image]

The sun is at your back and I need that glow in the tips of the hair and would like to brighten up the face too.. Is flash recommended for this? If yes what is the simplest way to soften the flash without any additional accessories.

I can go to f/3.6 WRT aperture. Please advise the best technique to get a pic like this.

Comment: related, if not duplicates:
http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50829/how-to-meter-to-clear-subject-details-with-a-strongly-backlit-scene-as-elena-sh

http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15557/how-can-i-take-a-sun-backlight-portrait-like-these-examples

Comment: The second one looks like an exact duplicate to me :-) @ElegantCoder - what makes you think this *can* be achieved without additional accessories?

Comment: @PhilipKendall : I am just a beginner in photography and wanted to tryout something like this. I don't have much of accessories with me thats why I mentioned the point in the question.

Comment: @MikeW : thanks. The second link answered my question.

Comment: @ElegantCoder you don't need a reflector for this, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is time the shot correctly.

The closer to sunset you shoot the lower the intensity of the sunlight compared to the light from the open sky. You can see in the image you posted you can see the position of the sun that is very low to the horizon.

This was shot just before sunset with no reflectors or other light sources:

[image]

The shot linked to in [**this question**](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15557/how-can-i-take-a-sun-backlight-portrait-like-these-examples) might have been done with a reflector as the light on the face is hard and warm (golden) just like the sunlight.

The image you posted the light on the subject's face is very diffuse and slightly cooler in colour, like the light you get from a clear blue sky.